# Ajax returns only first result in a PHP while loop

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am building a chat application and when I click the available users list (which is generated from a php while loop) the chat area is supposed to carry the information of that user and previous chat history (if any). However, for some reason ajax onclick keeps returning just the first user on the list into the chat area.

I have tried different methods of getting each user's id from the users-list (a separate php file) and passing it to the active-chat area (another php file) using ajax. I believe I'm missing something or doing something wrong. Every suggestion or different approach will be very much appreciated.

User's List PHP Code:

```
<?php
// this php is an include in another php file if certain conditions are met.
while($users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    
    // the list of users generated into the home page
    $output .= '<li id="contact" class="get-user-chats">
                    <input type="hidden" id="getUserId" value="'.$users['user_id'].'"/>
                    <span class="avatar"><img src="'.$users['display_pic'].'" height="42" width="42" alt="Generic placeholder image" />
                        <span class="'.$users['online_status'].'"></span>
                    </span>
                    <div class="chat-info flex-grow-1">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">'.$users['full_name'].'</h5>
                        <p class="card-text text-truncate">
                            This is just a test message to see if the truncate feature works
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat-meta text-nowrap">
                        <small class="float-end mb-25 chat-time">4:14 PM</small>
                        <span class="badge bg-danger rounded-pill float-end">3</span>
                    </div>   
                </li>';
                            
}
?>
```

Ajax Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.users-list').click(function(){
            //users-list is a class from the home page where the users list displays in a div
            var $container = $(this).find(".get-user-chats");
            var chatid = $container.find("#getUserId").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: './code/active-chat.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    chatuserid: chatid
                },
                success: function(response){
                    //alert(chatid)
                    $('.get-active-chat-user').html(response);
                },
                dataType: 'text'
                });
            });
        });
```

active-chat.php

```
<?php 
// active-chat.php
session_start();
define('BASEPATH', true);
require "../../../../private/engine.php";
$chatid = $_POST['chatuserid'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '{$chatid}'";
$fetchdata = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

while($sub = mysqli_fetch_array($fetchdata)){
    ?>
    <header class="chat-header">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <div class="sidebar-toggle d-block d-lg-none me-1">
                <i data-feather="menu" class="font-medium-5"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="avatar avatar-border user-profile-toggle m-0 me-1">
                <img src="<?php echo $sub['display_pic']; ?>" alt="avatar" height="36" width="36" />
                <span class="<?php echo $sub['online_status']; ?>"></span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mb-0"><?php echo $sub['full_name'] ?></h6>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <i data-feather="phone-call" class="cursor-pointer d-sm-block d-none font-medium-2 me-1"></i>
            <i data-feather="video" class="cursor-pointer d-sm-block d-none font-medium-2 me-1"></i>
            <!-- <i data-feather="search" class="cursor-pointer d-sm-block d-none font-medium-2"></i> -->
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn-icon btn btn-transparent hide-arrow btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i data-feather="more-vertical" id="chat-header-actions" class="font-medium-2"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="chat-header-actions">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">View Contact</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mute Notifications</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Block Contact</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Clear Chat</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Report</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<?php } ?>
```

Screenshot of the Chat Screen:
[Chat Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qf0h.png)

I have researched on related topics but none of them seems to address my specific issue.

Comment: Your 3rd snippet will always only run 1 loop, unless somehow multiple users have the same `user_id`. It is unclear in what you shared how your first snippet is actually used, and we don't know what the variable `$sql` holds in that case. If it's the same `$sql` as the 3rd snippet, then it will only ever return 1 row unless multiple users have the same `user_id`.

Comment: .users-list is the container, you should listen for click in your entries, so your li's in your case.

Comment: The $sql variable holds the SQL select statement that fetches the users from the database which includes my first php snippet if mysqli_num_rows is greater than 1